# How to set default directory for Emacs 27.1 app?

Tags: macos, catalina, customization, emacs

I just upgraded Emacs to 27.1 using `brew cask`. One noticeable change is that when I launch the app and `c-x c-f` the directory is `/` instead of `~/`.

This really bothers me, is there a way to change it back?

Comment: The directory is the root directory??  What's the *exact* directory that you have to use to launch the app?  As for `~/` that a shortcut to your home directory.  `~/` = `$HOME` = `/Users/DreamLinuxer/`  See [Bash Tilde Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html) for more info.

Comment: I just open it from spotlight, in 26.3 it is always my home directory but after upgrading it becomes `/`.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean by "it."  What is "it is always..." and "after upgrading it becomes..." referencing?  Where are you seeing this?  Can you post a screen shot?

Comment: When I open emacs from spotlight and try to open a file using `c-x c-f` this is what shows up https://i.imgur.com/RM1sQih.png . But in 26.3 the path is `~/` instead of `/`.

Comment: does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60464/changing-the-default-folder-in-emacs or https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/4253/how-to-start-emacs-with-a-custom-user-emacs-directory/

Comment: I have read those posts, but I think my question is a little different here. I still want `default-directory` to be the current working directory, but I don't know why the CWD for launching emacs from spotlight changed after upgrading.

Comment: Ok...it's making more sense now.  You want to change the default home directory.  Your configuration changed (somehow).  See this post for modifying your `.emacs` to set your default home directory - https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27020/change-emacs-home-directory-for-all-purposes

Comment: I think it's not about `.emacs`, because the behavior of emacs is exactly what I want (using CWD as `default-directory`) and it works as I expected when I launching it from terminal. The problem is the CWD is `/` when I launching emacs from spotlight, but in 26 it is `~/` so I suspect that the problem comes from the wrapper of Emacs.app.

Comment: The behaviour you now see is normal macos behaviour.  Which version of emacs 26 did you use.   The pure gnu one or the Mac specific patched one?

Comment: I use the one from `brew cask`, which is from https://emacsformacosx.com/

Comment: This bug also occurs if you download 27.1-1 from https://emacsformacosx.com/

Comment: This issue has been raised at https://github.com/caldwell/build-emacs/issues/98

Comment: “Looks like the fix will be in 27.2.” https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=44446#11

Comment: Let's nice, this has been bugging me for quite some time.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue after installing Emacs 27.1, my default directory became `"/"`

I could fix it by adding the following to my .emacs file.

```
(setq default-directory "~/")
(setq command-line-default-directory "~/")
```

Comment: I tried adding `(setq default-directory "~/")` to my .emacs, but when I `c-x c-f` the default directory is still `/`. But weirdly, if I switch to another buffer like `*scratch*` then it becomes `~/`. So I think maybe this is related to some unknown change of `*GNU Emacs` buffer.

Comment: Ah, I inhibit my splash screen so didn't noticed. To get the splash screen to also start in ~/ add the additional line `(setq command-line-default-directory "~/")`. I'll update the answer

Comment: This has the drawback that `emacs -nw foo.c` will open ~/foo.c and not ./foo.c.

Comment: For spacemacs users this needs to be in the `dotspacemacs/user-init` section not `user-config` as it needs to be loaded before subsequent packages. Sigh. Seems they've known about this forever but still released it https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2020-04/msg00240.html

Comment: @TurePålsson The problem seems gone using `'emacsclient -nw -a "" -c "$@"'` -- I alias it in my .zshrc file, `alias sp='emacsclient -nw -a "" -c "$@"'`. Files seem to open correctly from the command line.

Answer (score 3):

I have worked around this issue by editing /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs, inserting

```
Dir.chdir(ENV['HOME'])
```

before the call to exec at line 69

```
exec [emacs[:exe], emacs[:exe]], *ARGV
```

This is obviously just a temporary workaround, but it restores the previous behaviour of Emacs 26 without modifying any of my configuration or affecting Emacs command line calls, since it only modifies the Finder launch.

I've also posted this at https://github.com/caldwell/build-emacs/issues/98#issuecomment-720609277 EDIT: “Looks like the fix will be in 27.2.” https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=44446#11

Comment: This *almost* worked for me, but when I run from the command-line, I need relative path names to work.  I changed `Dir.chdir(ENV['HOME'])` to: `if ENV['PWD']\n    Dir.chdir(ENV['PWD'])\n  else\n    Dir.chdir(ENV['HOME'])\n  end` . That did the trick! (sorry about the bad formatting)

Answer (score 3):

Following the lead of @rptb1 , I modified /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs, inserting

```ruby
  if ENV['PWD']
    Dir.chdir(ENV['PWD'])
  else
    Dir.chdir(ENV['HOME'])
  end
```

before the call to `exec`:

```ruby
exec [emacs[:exe], emacs[:exe]], *ARGV
```

The advantage of this over the previous answer is that if you start emacs with the `open` command, you'll get the current working directory, which is normally what you'd expect, instead of your home directory.  This is critical for me because I often use the command-line to open a file in the current directory.

Although this is mostly a duplicate of his answer, I am posting it as a new answer because my comment on *his* answer came out so badly formatted.  I hope the upcoming bug fix preserves the current directory, as emacs 26 did.

Comment: Did you get this behaviour from `open` before this bug was introduced?

Comment: @rbtb1: The behavior I got from `open` before I upgraded to emacs 27.1 more-or-less matches the behavior I now get with 27.1 combined with this script change. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes thanks. I use [emacsclient](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsClient) for this kind of thing so I never noticed it.  Let's hope 27.2 comes out soon so we can discard these dirty hacks :)